# Cannot insert data using Listview

Tags: asp.net, listview, insert

**Background**

I am building a user entry form in ASP.net 4.0 using Visual Studio Professional 2010 and C# with SQL Server 2005 as the backend.  This form was built using the wizards Microsoft provides. In other words I did not not write the code for this, but rather used the options provided to me by clicking and filling the dialogue boxes for the listview. I have not customized this in any way. The Edit, Delete, Update and Insert are enabled.

This form uses a dropdownlist to filter the records. There are two tables in this form: A Personnel table listing paramedics and a Preferences table listing their shift preferences. This form will filter for a specific paramedic and then add multiple shift preference.

The problem is that when I run the page and attempt to insert data using the Insert command I receive an error message. The error message reads:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Preference_PK', table
>   'ColdFusion_Apps.dbo.Preferences'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails. The statement has been terminated.  Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert
>   the value NULL into column 'Preference_PK', table
>   'ColdFusion_Apps.dbo.Preferences'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails. The statement has been terminated.

How can I fix this ?   I suspect the issue is the primary key column of my Preferences table, but if I followed all the wizards and took just the default options, why would this be happening ?

**SQL code to create the database**

```
 CREATE TABLE Preferences
(
  Preference_PK INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
, Name_FK INT NOT NULL
, Preference VARCHAR(20)
)
;

INSERT INTO Preferences (Name_FK, Preference)
VALUES
 (1,'Make a Selection')
,(2,'Make a Selection')
,(3,'Make a Selection')
,(4,'Make a Selection')
,(5,'Make a Selection')
;

ALTER TABLE Preferences
ADD CONSTRAINT PreferencePrimaryKey PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(Preference_PK)
;

ALTER TABLE Preferences
ADD CONSTRAINT PersonnelForeignKey FOREIGN KEY(Personnel_FK) REFERENCES Personnel(Personnel_PK)
;
CREATE TABLE Personnel
(
Personnel_PK INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
, Name VARCHAR(50) NULL
, Title VARCHAR(20) NULL
, DateHired SMALLDATETIME NULL
)
;

INSERT INTO Personnel (Name, Title, DateHired)
VALUES
 ('Abes, Benjamin','Lieutenant','March 18, 2004')
,('Acton, Traci','Paramedic','May 30, 1991')
,('Adams, Bunny','Paramedic','January 4, 2001')
,('Alcime, Gabner','EMT','April 12, 2007')
,('Angel, Craig','Paramedic','November 5, 1992')
;

ALTER TABLE Personnel
ADD CONSTRAINT PersonnelPrimaryKey PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(Personnel_PK)
;
```

**ASP.NET 4.0 code**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="Personnel_sql"
        DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Personnel_PK">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Personnel_sql" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ColdFusion_AppsConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Name], [Personnel_PK] FROM [Personnel]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Preference_sql" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ColdFusion_AppsConnectionString %>"
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Preferences] WHERE [Preference_PK] = @Preference_PK"
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Preferences] ([Personnel_FK], [Preference], [Preference_PK]) VALUES (@Personnel_FK, @Preference, @Preference_PK)"
        SelectCommand="SELECT Preference_PK, Personnel_FK, Preference FROM Preferences WHERE (Personnel_FK = @Personnel_FK)"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Preferences] SET [Personnel_FK] = @Personnel_FK, [Preference] = @Preference WHERE [Preference_PK] = @Preference_PK">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Preference_PK" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Personnel_FK" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Preference" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Preference_PK" Type="Int32" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Personnel_FK" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Personnel_FK" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Preference" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Preference_PK" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Preference_PK" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Preference_PK" DataSourceID="Preference_sql"
        InsertItemPosition="LastItem">
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                    <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Preference_PKLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Preference_PK") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Personnel_FKLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Personnel_FK") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="PreferenceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Preference") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Preference_PKLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Preference_PK") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Personnel_FKTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Personnel_FK") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PreferenceTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Preference") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <table runat="server" style="">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        No data was returned.
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Preference_PKTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Preference_PK") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Personnel_FKTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Personnel_FK") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PreferenceTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Preference") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                    <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Preference_PKLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Preference_PK") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Personnel_FKLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Personnel_FK") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="PreferenceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Preference") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table runat="server">
                <tr runat="server">
                    <td runat="server">
                        <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                            <tr runat="server" style="">
                                <th runat="server">
                                </th>
                                <th runat="server">
                                    Preference_PK
                                </th>
                                <th runat="server">
                                    Personnel_FK
                                </th>
                                <th runat="server">
                                    Preference
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server">
                    <td runat="server" style="">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <SelectedItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                    <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Preference_PKLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Preference_PK") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Personnel_FKLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Personnel_FK") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="PreferenceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Preference") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </SelectedItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Question**

- How can I insert values into my database using this Listview ?
- What am I doing wrong ?
- Please spell this out for me explicitly. I am not a programmer, so with me, you cannot be too simplistic.

Comment: What your error is telling you is that your code is trying to enter a NULL value in the Preference_PK column when you have specified that it should never allow a NULL and should automatically increment a unique identifier.

Your insert statement looks to be wrong as you are trying to write data into a Personnel_FK column which doesnt exist in the Preferences table - can you let me know what should be written to the database in your insert and I can try and provide an answer for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this insert statement instead.
You don't include the identity key in the insert statement.

> InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Preferences] ( [Preference],
>   [Preference_PK]) VALUES (@Preference, @Preference_PK)"